# Passing unknown ArrayList type to method

Tags: java, arraylist

Say I have these two ArrayLists:

```
ArrayList<Book> book = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Journal> journal = new ArrayList<>();
```

`Book` and `Journal` are two different classes.

Both `Book` and `Journal` objects have a `getYear()` method. I want to make a method that passes in an unknown ArrayList type and compares a passed in year to an object in the list. The following code is in main:

```
public static void fooBar(int year, ArrayList<?> list)
{
    if(list.get(0).getYear() == year) // does not work!
    {
    }
}
```

If an unknown type is passed into the method, I cannot use that object's methods (`getYear()`). How can I do this without making two methods that do the same thing (one for `Book` and one for `Journal`)?

Comment: Do `Book` and `Journal` share a superclass or interface that defines `getYear()`?

Comment: My method signature was wrong, I edited the question.

Comment: What @JonK asked... If it doesn't you should make one and that would solve your problem

Answer (score 14):

You can make an interface (if it doesn't already exist) (possibly named `HasYear`) that declares the `getYear()` method, and have `Book` and `Journal` implement it.

Then you can have your `fooBar` method take an `ArrayList` of some type parameter that is a `HasYear`.

```
public static void fooBar(int year, ArrayList<? extends HasYear> list)
```

The `? extends` is due to the fact it's a consumer and not a producer.

Comment: I am learning Java in school and I haven't learned what an interface is. Why can't Java just infer the type of list I send into the method so I can use that object's methods?

Comment: With a `List<?>` parameter, you are allowed to pass a list of anything, e.g. `List<Integer>`, `List<Foo>`, `List<?>`, etc., which won't necessarily have a `getYear()` method.  The compiler won't allow you to call a method it can't guarantee exists.

Comment: Your list is specified in the method as `List<?>`, so it could contain anything.

Comment: if I call the method like this: `fooBar(2015, bookList)`, and `bookList` is an ArrayList of type `Book`, then shouldn't I be able to use `Book`'s methods in `fooBar`?

Comment: @MortalMan it sounds like you want to use a language other than Java, like Ruby, Scala or Javascript.

Comment: You have declared a method that can take a list of any objects. Regardless of how you call it, the method itself cannot be compiled because calling `getYear()` on an arbitrary object doesn't make sense.

Comment: In this case, may I suggest an interface `Publication`, of which both a `Book` and `Journal` are? There may be other commonalities as well.

Answer (score 4):

Like JonK said, if they share a superclass or interface that defines getYear() then this will be made easier. Actually, the *have* to have either of those two relationships to make your proposed relationship.

```
interface HasYear {
    public int getYear();
}
```

Book.java

```
public class Book implements HasYear{
    //...
    public int getYear(){/*YOUR IMPLEMENTATION*/}
}
```

Journal.java

```
public class Journal implements HasYear{
    //...
    public int getYear(){/*YOUR IMPLEMENTATION*/}
}
```

Now, you can create and use your ArrayList like this:

```
public static void fooBar(int year, ArrayList<? extends HasYear> list){
    if(list.get(0).getYear() == year){
        //yay
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have both `Book` and `Journal` extend a common superclass (`Publication` perhaps?) or implement a common interface which defines the `getYear()` method:

```
public abstract class Publication {
    private int year;

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public Publication(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
}
```

If you then change your `Book` and `Journal` class declarations and constructors:

```
public class Book extends Publication {

     public Book(int year, ...) {
         super(year);
         ...
     }
```

```
public class Journal extends Publication {

     public Journal(int year, ...) {
         super(year);
         ...
     }
```

You could then pass around a list of `Publication` objects:

```
public void fooBar(int year, List<? extends Publication> list) { ... }
```

Because it's `Publication` that defines the `getYear()` method, you can freely use it on objects contained within `list`.

Comment: As other answers have demonstrated, you can also use an interface to accomplish the same thing in much the same way.

Comment: using `List<Publication>` as argument allows you to call `list.add(new Book())` regardless of the actual type of the content of `list`, which is very dangerous. `? extends Publication` prevents that.

Comment: @njzk2 I suppose it really depends on what you're doing with the list, but yes, point taken. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @njzk2 Umm... no: When the type is `List<Publication>`, then you can only pass in a `List<Publication>`, and then you can add a `Book` - that's fine. But as the list is only *read* here, allowing a `List<? extends Publication>` increases the flexibility (it can be called with a `List<Publication>`, but also with a `List<Book>`), and is more idiomatic in terms of [PECS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)

Answer (score 1):

Everyone discussed about the right way of doing it, such as associating your object with a super class containing your desired method, but if you want some fancy implementation without using super class, you can try lambda expression:

```
ArrayList<Book> book = new ArrayList<>();
book.stream().limit(1).filter(s->s.getYear()==year).forEach(yourcode)
```

I know this is not what you wanted but you have right solution from other comments.